# Node js client for grpc server

Tags: node.js, client, chat, grpc

I have GRPC server running using openssl - static way and I am trying to connect to server using nodejs client

I do not see any error but I do not see its connecting to server either.
Please share if you have any sample.

Please refer code below:

```
    var rootCertPath = path.join('.','.', 'server-root.PEM');
    var privateCertPath = path.join('.','.', 'server-private.PEM');
    var domainCertPath = path.join('.','.', 'server-domain.PEM');

    var rootCert = fs.readFileSync(rootCertPath);
    var privateCert = fs.readFileSync(privateCertPath);
    var domainCert = fs.readFileSync(domainCertPath);

    var buf1 = new Buffer('rootCert');
    var buf2 = new Buffer('privateCert');
    var buf3 = new Buffer('domainCert');

    var chat_proto = grpc.load("Chat.proto").com.company.grpc;
    var client = new chat_proto.ChatService('https://servervip:443',grpc.credentials.createSsl(buf1,buf2,buf3));
```

Chat.proto

```
  syntax = "proto3";

        // Service definition.

            service ChatService {
              // Sends a chat
               rpc chat(stream ChatMessage) returns (stream ChatMessageFromServer) {}
            }
        // The request message containing the user's name.
        message ChatMessage {
          string name = 1;
          string message = 2;
        }

        // The response message containing the greetings
        message ChatMessageFromServer {
            string name = 1;
            string message = 2;
        }
```

//Code to make a request

```
var username = process.argv[2];
var stdin = process.openStdin();

function main() {
    console.log("starting");
    console.log(client); // prints { '$channel': Channel {} }
    var chat=client.chat();
    chat.on('data', function(msg) {
      console.log(msg.name + ': ' + msg.message);
        console.log("after message");
    });

    stdin.addListener('data',function(input) {
        chat.write({ name: username, message: input.toString().trim()
        }); 

    });

}
main();
```

Comment: Can you include the code you are using to actually make the request? Are you seeing any specific errors? Other than that, you shouldn't be using the server's private key and certificate chain data on the client side. You just need root certs, and if you want to do TLS-based client authentication, the client should have its own ckeys.

Comment: added details  in the original post  as suggested - refer below sections 

//Code to make a request
//Chat.proto

I tried with root cert only approach and still the same behavior
I do not have any requirement for now to authenticate client

Comment: >> Creating client scenario 1: var client = new chat_proto.ChatService('https://servervip:443',creds);
No error but no response

>> Error creating client scenario 2: var client = new chat_proto.ChatService('servervip',creds);
E0519 11312 ssl_transport_security.c:601] Could not load any root certificate.
E0519 11312 ssl_transport_security.c:1315] Cannot load server root certificates.
E0519 11312 security_connector.c:837] Handshaker factory creation failed with TSI_INVALID_ARGUMENT.
E0519 11312 secure_channel_create.c:127] Failed to create secure subchannel for secure name 'servervip'

Comment: That looks like an error. Are you sure your root certificate file is in the right format?

Comment: yeah - I am on windows - 

it the .PEM file and if I just rename it to .CER I am able to see the certificate and if I try 
opensl verify *.PEM gives me response OK

Comment: OK, to be clear, a root certificate file is a list of public keys of trusted certificate authorities. The common case for providing your own is if you have self-signed certificates and you want to trust that signer. Is that the situation here?

Comment: Here root_cert I was referring to was having only root cert *.PEM file
I have tried adding the complete cert chain - root_cert.PEM[ having -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----<domain cert> -----END CERTIFICATE----------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----<intermediate cert> -----END CERTIFICATE----------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----<root cert> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
]and seeing the same result

Comment: so good new is - below thing worked for me
var creds = grpc.credentials.createSsl(rootCert);
var client = new chat_proto.ChatService('servervip:443',creds);
Looks like an issue with the cert - I used the default roots.PEM in grpc client and it worked for me. will look internally to have correct root of my own certificate chain

Answer (score 1):

so good new is - below thing worked for me

```
var rootCertPath = path.join('.','.', 'roots.PEM');
var rootCert = fs.readFileSync(rootCertPath);
var chat_proto = grpc.load("Chat.proto").com.americanexpress.grpc.chat;
var client = new chat_proto.ChatService('servervip:443',grpc.credentials.createSsl(rootCert));
```

Looks like an issue with the cert - I used the default roots.PEM in grpc client and it worked for me. will look internally to have correct root of my servervip CA certificate chain.

Thanks all for your support